# Python - Default Counter Variable in For loop

Tags: python

Is there any default Counter Variable in For loop?

Comment: What do you mean by "default"? Why do you need a counter variable?

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you're asking, you should type more than a single sentence to a question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, you give it a name: `for i in range(10): ...`

If you want to iterate over elements of a collection in such a way that you get both the element and its index, the Pythonic way to do it is `for i,v in enumerate(l): print i,v` (where `l` is a list or any other object implementing the sequence protocol.)

Comment: Minor nit - `l` can be anything that implements the sequence protocol, not just a list.

Answer (score 7):

Generally, if you are looping through a list (or any iterator) and want the index as well, you use `enumerate`:

```
for i, val in enumerate(l):
   <do something>
```

Comment: There ain't not `enumerate` in your example.

Comment: I added the call to enumerate.

Comment: No enumerate. it should be enumerate(l)

Answer (score 5):

Simple question, simple answer :

```
for (i, value) in enumerate(alist):
    print i, value
```

output :

```
1 value
2 value
3 value
...
```

where "value" is the current value of alist (a list or something else).

Comment: i is zero-indexed, not 1-indexed.  To have the output start at 1 use the 'start' keyword argument.